# Signal exception in a PollingConsumer template after receive()

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

It's possible to signal an error after `Exchange exchange = consumer.receive();` using a `PollingConsumer` template in Apache Camel? If you throw an error from a bean processor, for example, Camel prints a stacktrace in the console and stop's the routing. Is possible to do the same using PollingConsumer, probably retrying the message again? There's this `PollingConsumerPollStrategy` but it looks like that's for error handling **before** receive().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No polling consumer is a queue based exchange, so it returns an exchange where there was a successful exchange retrieved. You can use receive with timeout that throws a timeout exception if an exchange cannot be retrieved within that time.

If you want an exception, then use `Consumer` instead of `PollingConsumer`.